# How can I compare strings from database and userinput?

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to do a Examination Questionnaires. I'm retrieving the questions and choices from the database. I am using `h:inputText` inside the `ui:repeat`. But when I was is trying to get the answer it only duplicate the last answer. I am just new in using JSF, I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Here is the JSF:

```
<h:body>
<h:outputLabel>Examination</h:outputLabel>

<h:form>
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{bean.q}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <br/>
        #{status.index+1}.
        #{item.question}<br/>
        A. #{item.ans_1}<br/>
        B. #{item.ans_2}<br/>
        C. #{item.ans_3}<br/>
        D. #{item.ans_4}<br/>
        <h:outputLabel value="Answer:" />
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.answer}" required="true">
            <f:validateLength maximum="1"/>
            <f:validateRegex pattern="(^[_A-D]$)" />
        </h:inputText>
        <br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
<br/>
<h:commandButton id="btn" value="Check" action="#{bean.check}"/>

</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Here is the bean:

```
public List<Return> getQ(){
DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager();
Connection conn = db.connection("jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-","sa","1234567890");
List<Return> qList = new ArrayList<Return>();
try{
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM [JavaEE].[dbo].[tbl_Finals]");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        Return e=new Return();
        e.setQuestion(rs.getString("question"));
        e.setAns_1(rs.getString("a1"));
        e.setAns_2(rs.getString("a2"));
        e.setAns_3(rs.getString("a3"));
        e.setAns_4(rs.getString("a4"));
        qList.add(e);
    }
    conn.close();
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
}
return qList;
}

public void check(){

    DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager();
    Connection conn = db.connection("jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP","sa","1234567890");
    try{
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM [JavaEE].[dbo].[tbl_Finals]");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            i++;
            System.out.println(getAnswer());
            if(getAnswer().equals(rs.getString("ans"))){
                c++;
                System.out.println(i+ ". CORRECT");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(i+ ". WRONG");
            }
        }
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception k){;
    }
System.out.println("Your score is: " +c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1)

Effectively you have multiple `inputTexts` that point to the same field `#{bean.answer}`. When submitting the form, each of your inputTexts calls `bean.setAnswer(..)` and you end up having the value of the last `inputText` in that field.

Add a field tou your `Return` class:

```
public class Return {
  ...
  private String userAnswerInput;
  public void setUserAnswerInput(..){..};
  public String getUserAnswerInput(){..};
}
```

and change your input to `<h:inputText value="#{item.userAnswerInput}" ...>`

This way you'll have answers from users filled into `Return` instances corresponding to asked questions each.

2)

You'll have to modify you `check()` method to loop through your List of `Return` instances.

3)

You shouldn't build that List of `Return` instances within your getter as this is invoked several times. Instead create the list in a separte public method annoted with `@PostContruct`. The getter should be reduced to `public List<Return> getQ(){return qList;}`.

Comment: And OP should not do jdbc in jsf 'controllers' but in services. And some more things. Starting with a good tutorial would help

Comment: Hi, I've transferred all my setters and getters to another class. But when I entered a value I am getting null values. How should I modify my <code>check()</code> method to get the data from user input? Thank you!